# Action Sript error while calling .net web service

Tags: actionscript-3

I am using .net web service and flex 4.6 to develop web application. In my application I am getting error message while receiving web service response.

"SOAP Response cannot be decoded. Raw response: "

From Login to Landing page there are 3-4 web service call which doesn't give me error but there is one transaction where i call web service it gives this error.

```
<RESPONSE>
<STATUS>SUCCESS</STATUS>
<ENTITY>LEAD</ENTITY>
<MESSAGE>Lead successfully updated</MESSAGE>
<DATA>
    <Lead>CREATED/UPDATED</Lead>
</DATA>
```

This is my response in String format comes from web service.

can anybody help me out

Answer (score 0):

Note that your response is malformed. There is no `</RESPONSE>` tag at end of your xml struture.
XML Should be

```
<RESPONSE>
<STATUS>SUCCESS</STATUS>
<ENTITY>LEAD</ENTITY>
<MESSAGE>Lead successfully updated</MESSAGE>
<DATA>
    <Lead>CREATED/UPDATED</Lead>
</DATA>
</RESPONSE>
```

Comment: I double checked it, </RESPONSE> tag is there, it was miss by me while creating this message.

Comment: are you talking about response encoding/decoding or request encoding/decoding. In my web service there is only one parameter having string type and return type is also string. I guess there is no need to Enocde & decode.

Comment: Your .net Web service should return encoded string value after that flex side need to decode (unecape/escape() in as3) your webservice response. But i am not sure this will correct your problem.

Comment: do you think, string values require serialization to transport over the network.

Comment: absolutely right.Make sure that your webservice is throw any exception .If so try return that exception as XML String. Also Check stackoverflow.com/questions/2581799/flex-3-and-soap-response

Comment: But in my web service there is no exception. I debug it and it works fine there no exception in my web service. Please suggest something its no bottle neck for me

Comment: Hi Raja, can you please suggest me on this. I double check the web service it is working fine with IE.